# How to use a Symbol from a font in React Native/Expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I do this when working on React Web, after linking my fonts and associated CSS:

```
<span className="symbol-code" />
```

Is it possible to use the same resources (fonts and styles) to display the symbol as text in React Native with Expo?

Comment: use `<Text/>` component, obviously we don't have <span/> in ReactNative

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IconMoon like me, you can do this:

1 - Put your `font.ttf` and `selection.json` files in `./assets/fonts`:

```
./assets/fonts/my-font/my-font.ttf
./assets/fonts/my-font/selection.json
```

2 - Create an IconSet component:

```
import { useFonts } from "expo-font";
import { createIconSetFromIcoMoon } from "@expo/vector-icons";

const IconSet = createIconSetFromIcoMoon(
  require("./assets/fonts/my-font/selection.json"),
  "my-font",
  "my-font.ttf"
);


export function MyFontIconSet({ iconName, size, color }) {
  const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    'my-font': require("./assets/fonts/my-font/my-font.ttf"),
  });

  if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return null;
  }

  return <IconSet name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
}
```

3 - Use your IconSet:

```
<MyFontIconSet iconName="symbol-code" size={45} color="red" />
```